# How do I extract parameters out of $.post?

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP code, and HTML code. I learn the `$.post`.

I would like use later on the elements of the getting result array: `FileName`, `Width`, and so on.

How can I do this?

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$json_obj = (object) array('FileName' => "vonat.jpg", 'Width'  => "155", 'Height' => "150");
$json_obj2 = (object) array('FileName' => "pum.jpg", 'Width' => "222", 'Height' => "200");
$json_obj = $json_obj2;
$json = json_encode($json_obj);
//   echo  $json_obj -> FileName;
//echo  $json_obj -> Width;
echo $json;
return $json;
?>
```

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.post( 
             "kep.php",
             { name: "Bártfai" },
             function(result) {
var imageFileName = result["FileName"];
alert(„imageFileName”+imageFileName);   this is didnt working
var element=$("<div />");
element.data(„FileName”, imageFilename);    I would like to build up/construct an <DIV> 
    element
  $('#stage').html(result); this is working
//$('#stage').append(result);
             }
          );
      },"json");
   });
   </script>

</head>

<body>
   <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
   <div id="stage" style="background-color:yellow;">
          STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use it later in javascript ?
If it's the case, just put it in a global variable:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var resultForLater;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.post( 
             "kep.php",
             { name: "Bártfai" },
             function(result) {
resultForLater = result; //Put it in the global variable so you can use it elsewhere
var imageFileName = result["FileName"];
alert(„imageFileName”+imageFileName);   this is didnt working
var element=$("<div />");
element.data(„FileName”, imageFilename);    I would like to build up/construct an <DIV> 
    element
  $('#stage').html(result); this is working
//$('#stage').append(result);
             }
          );
      },"json");
   });
   </script>
```